# How to create a multidimensional array with JQuery -with .each()

Tags: jquery, each

I would like to create the following array with Jquery and a .each function:

I would like the JSON to look like **this:**

```
{
            "calendar_id": "1",
            "dishs": [
                 {
                    "dish_id": "11111",
                    "amount": "234234"
                },
                 {
                    "dish_id": "11112",
                    "amount": "234234"
                },
                 {
                    "dish_id": "11113",
                    "amount": "234234"
                }, ...]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14793">
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14794">
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14795">
```

`dish_id` is the id (i.e. amount_14794)
`amount` is the `val()` of that input.

Please note that `calendar_id` appears once in the beginning of the array.

Comment: @guradio it's a mess, I couldn't understand how to get the multidimensional part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a empty array then push a object that you build using each

```js
var obj = [];
$('.amount').each(function(i,v){
    obj.push({'dish_id':$(v).attr('id'),'amount': $(v).val()});
});
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14793" value="1">
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14794" value="2">
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14795" value="3">
```

if you want the other properties you can create a object with them first and then append to the empty `dishs` property the new objects

```js
var obj = {
  "calendar_id": "1",
  "dishs": []
};
$('.amount').each(function(i, v) {
  obj.dishs.push({
    'dish_id': $(v).attr('id'),
    'amount': $(v).val()
  });
});
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14793" value="1">
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14794" value="2">
<input type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14795" value="3">
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resultObj = {};
  resultObj.calendar_id = 1;
  resultObj.dishs = [];

  $(".amount").each(function() {

    var currentDish = {};
    currentDish.dish_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("amount_", ""); //set the dish_id by grabing only number out of element id

    currentDish.amount = $(this).val(); //set the amount

    resultObj.dishs.push(currentDish);

  });

  console.log(resultObj);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="12345" class="amount" id="amount_14793">
<input type="number" value="12345" class="amount" id="amount_14794">
<input type="number" value="12345" class="amount" id="amount_14795">
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code of what you are looking for:

```js
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var paramsToSend = {};
  var i = 1;
  var amount = ''
  $("input[name='number[]']").each(function(){
    paramsToSend['dish_id_' + i] = $(this).val();
    i++;
  });
  
   $("#dataToSend").html(JSON.stringify(paramsToSend));
   
   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'URL_HERE',
         data: {params:JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)},
         success: function(data) {
          console.log("SUCCESS!!!");
         }
   });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputsl">
<input name="number[]" type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14793">
<input name="number[]" type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14794">
<input name="number[]" type="number" class="amount" id="amount_14795">
</div>
<button id="submit">
Submit
</button>

<div id="dataToSend"></div>
```